# How to create login configuration

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning react and I need some help,
Creating a login page, cant set the state correctly

How to set up the onSubmit and onChange in the input props

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoginInfo extends Component {
  state = {
    info: {
      userName: '',
      password: ''
    }
  };

  updateInfo = e => {
    this.setState({ info: { [e.target.name]: e.target.value } });
  };
  submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="text-center container mt-4" style={{ width: '50%' }}>
        <form className="px-4 py-3" onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Username: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email@example.com"
              className="form-control"
              name="username"
              value={this.state.info.userName}
              onChange={this.updateInfo}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Password"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.info.password}
              onChange={this.updateInfo}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mt-3">
            Sign in
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginInfo;
```

should I change the Inputs to components and then put props in the components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is when you fill one input and try to change another, the first one is being cleared out, right ?

It's due to the fact, that you create a new `info` object in your state. If you change your `updateInfo` function to:

```
updateInfo = e => {
   this.setState({ info: { ...this.state.info, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } });
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to be more specific I get this error: "Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component." and the data is undefined

Comment: You are getting this because if you input `login`, your `password` is not being created, again due to the fact how you update the state. So one of the two fields becomes an uncontrolled input.